# How to prove this equation is non-linear?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Does anyone can prove this equation is non-linear?

I tried many methods but still cannot prove it. Please help.

Here is the [question:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfyjV.jpg)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfyjV.jpg]

Comment: Well, $f(1,1,1,1)=1$; can you find $x,y$ with $f(x)=f(y)=0$ but $x+y=(1,1,1,1)$?

Answer (score 2):

As long as $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ are not all $1$, $x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 $ will be $0$ so the function will equal $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4$. Which *is* linear.

So you are trying to find an example where $f(x + y) \ne f(x) + f(y)$, and you better take one of $x, y$ or $x + y$ to be $(1,1,1,1)$ in order to get the counterexample. Let's say $x$ is $(1,1,1,1)$. Now pick something for $y$ and see if you can show $f(x + y) \ne f(x) + f(y)$.